# Standard C function atof returns segmentation faults when using with strtok

Tags: c, strtok, atof

I have problem with using atof and strtok.

```
#include<stdio.h> // printf
#include<stdlib.h> // atof
#include<string.h> // strtok

int main()
{
  char buf[256]="123.0 223.2 2314.2";
  char* tp;

  printf("buf : %s\n", buf);
  tp = strtok(buf," ");
  printf("tp : %g ", atof(tp));
  while (tp!=NULL) {
    tp = strtok(NULL," ");
    printf("%g ", atof(tp));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I can compile above code and it returns no errors or warning messages.
but when I execute "a.out", then it returns segmentation fault like below.

```
78746 Segmentation fault: 11  ./a.out
```

I don't know what is problem. as I see, above code doesn't compound syntactic error.

Comment: It's a good idea to learn how to use a debugger, and then do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `tp` becomes null you do `atof` on it!

Rewrite your loop like this:

```
int main()
{
  char buf[256]="123.0 223.2 2314.2";
  char* tp;

  printf("buf : %s\n", buf);
  tp = strtok(buf," ");
  printf("tp :");
  while (tp!=NULL) {
    printf("%g ", atof(tp));
    tp = strtok(NULL," ");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing tp to atof without checking that it is non-null.